# Sind Relativsätze mit Genitiv-Präpositionen ungrammatisch?

Tags: genitive, relative-clause

Überall findet man nur prepositionale Relativsätze, die nur die Akkusativ- und Dativfälle betreffen. Theoretisch lässt sich aber auch ein Relativsatz mit Genitivpräpositionen bilden. Ich vermute, der würde so lauten:

> Das Kind, dank dessen (…)

oder

> Die Umstände, trotz derer (…)

- Sind Relativsätze mit Genitiv-Präpositionen abzuraten?
- Sind die sogar ungrammatisch? (Oder nur überhaupt nicht geläufig?)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Solche Konstruktionen sind grammatikalisch korrekt und ich würde behaupten, dass sie jeder versteht, dem Präpositionen mit Genitiv keine Probleme bereiten – was allerdings nicht für jeden Muttersprachler gilt. Bei den meisten Zielgruppen würde ich also nicht davon abraten, sie zu benutzen.

Es gibt sogar mit *[dessentwegen](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/dessentwegen)* und *[derentwegen](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/derentwegen)* eigene Worte für *wegen dessen* und *wegen derer* (analog zu *deinetwegen* statt *wegen dir),* die aber nicht mehr sehr geläufig sind:

> Der Tropfen, dessentwegen das Fass überlief.

Comment: Siehe [Grimm](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/GWB/call_wbgui_py_from_form?sigle=GWB&mode=Volltextsuche&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=JD00887#XJD00887), damals noch nur in Fügung mit *um*, "um deretwegen". Ich schreibe ausschließlich *deretwegen*, analog zu *seinetwegen*, worum ich aber nicht streiten würde. Bemerke auch: "Der Tropfen" ist kein Hauptsatz; Ein Bezug des Relativsatzes auf das Subjekt wäre logischer (?), da das Relativpronomen als Subjekt des Nebensatzes fungiert; Bzw. kann der Tropfen als Objekt selbst gebeugt stehen, so *Er gab den Tropfen, dessentwegen das ...* so oder so fungiert.

Answer (score 5):

Verben mit Genitivobjekt werden in der gesprochenen Umgangssprache eigentlich gar nicht mehr gebraucht. Sie sind noch typisch in geschriebener gehobener Sprache oder werden von versierten Rednern gebraucht. Sie sind aber immer etwas Auffälliges und Besonderes. Viele Verben mit Gen-Objekt werden in der Umgangssprache durch Verben mit Prep-Objekt ersetzt. Statt "ich erinnere mich nicht dieses Namens" sagt man heute "Ich erinnere mich nicht an diesen Namen/diesen Namen gehört zu haben." – Genitiv-Verben sind für die Umgangssprache einfach zu schwierig, da kommt man schnell in Schwierigkeiten und müsste überlegen, wie das zu konstruieren ist. Und Relativsätze mit Gen-Verben sind noch schwieriger. Da würde so mancher Normaldeutsche ganz schön in Schwierigkeiten kommen, und da gibt es sogar Fälle, wo man die Grammatik zu Rate ziehen müsste, weil es da auch allerhand Finessen gibt. Generell kann man sagen, dass solche Konstruktionen im Abnehmen sind, und nur Autoren oder Journalisten, die zeigen wollen, welche Sprachfertigkeiten sie haben, werfen mit solchen Sachen herum – manchmal. Für den Sprachunterricht (DaF) ist dieser Grammatikbereich eigentlich außerhalb des Normalen.

Der obengenannte Beispielsatz "Der Tropfen, dessentwegen das Fass überlief" klingt für mich recht gespreizt und unnatürlich. Das Natürliche für mich wäre "Der Tropfen, der das Fass zum Überlaufen brachte". Aber natürlich kann jeder den Stil, in dem er sprechen oder schreiben will, frei wählen.

Comment: Kannst Du ein Beispiel mit Finessen geben, für das jemand die Grammatik zu Rate ziehen müsste oder in dem zumindest Unterschiede zu analogen Situationen mit Dativ oder Akkusativ bestehen? Und nebenbei: Dass *dessentwegen* nicht mehr gebräuchlich ist, habe ich selbst geschrieben.

Comment: Bin kein Spezialist für Relativsätze mit Rel.pronomen im Genitiv. Da muß ich erstmal in Duden Zweifelsfälle nachschauen. - Ja, da finde ich auch schon was: Heißt es "Die Person, deren/derer er sich annahm"? Wenn du das auf Anhieb weißt, bist du gut.

Comment: Mein Sprachgefühl entscheidet sich da eindeutig für *derer.*

Comment: @rogermue "*Die Person, **der*** er sich annahm", aber "Die Person, ***deren** Problemen* er sich annahm"

Comment: Zitat: *"Verben mit Genitivobjekt werden in der gesprochenen Umgangssprache eigentlich gar nicht mehr gebraucht."* Ich möchte mich **dieser Behauptung annehmen,** die, wie du bald bemerken wirst **jeder Grundlage entbehrt** und ich möchte dich **eines Besseren belehren:** Ich will dich nicht **der Lüge bezichtigen,** aber man findet solche Konstruktionen durchaus im Alltag. Manche Personen **rühmen** sich **ihrer Fähigkeiten,** gelegentlich sogar so heftig, dass es **jeder Beschreibung spottet.** Man sollte ihnen **keines Blickes würdigen.** Werden sie ...

Comment: ... dann **einer Straftat überführt, entschlagen** sie sich oft **der Aussage** anstatt sich **ihrer Tat zu schämen.** Ein Schiedsrichter, der **seines Amtes waltet, verweist** einen Spieler **des Spielfeldes,** der dann **seiner Wege geht.**

Answer (score 1):

Du hast natürlich recht mit den Relativsätzen. Sie können sehr einfach mit dem Genitiv verwendet werden, und das ist auch nichts Exotisches: "Das Kind, dessen Mütze schief saß, sprach."

Ein Problem ist aber die Präposition "dank". Viele glauben, sie müsse mit dem Genitiv verwendet werden. 
Leider kennt zwar jeder derzeit Bastian Sicks "Der Dativ ist dem Genitiv sein Tod", aber viele schießen in ihrem blinden Bemühen, den Genitiv wieder zum Leben zu erwecken, über das Ziel hinaus. Ich vermute, sie gehen ohne Hinterfragung davon aus, dass alle Präpositionen, die etwas seltener sind und damit scheinbar "hochsprachlich" oder bildungssprachlich", den Genitiv erfordern. 
Die Präposition "dank" erfordert den DATIV, also wäre "dank dem" korrekt. Inzwischen hört man leider das falsche "dank dessen" recht oft. Unser Sprachgefühl sollte aber die Parallele zwischen dem Verb "danken" und der Präposition "dank" erkennen, denn "ich danke DEM Präsidenten" ist sehr selbstverständlich mit dem Dativ und wird bis jetzt auch noch nicht falsch mit dem Genitiv verwendet.

Nicht sauer sein bitte, das ist Kritik, kein Meckern.

Comment: "dank" ist durchaus eine Präposition, die sowohl mit dem Genitiv als auch dem Dativ verwendet werden kann - Am Genitiv ist hier *überhaupt nichts* auszusetzen (Siehe Duden).